# What are possible number of ordered trees with n nodes considering values at every node to be same?

Tags: tree, computer-science

For example, for n =3  there are two such trees possible, first tree as the straight skew tree and other rooted at middle.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram MathWorld have a good explanation of this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinaryTree.html

Comment: It can be any tree not binary tree.